# I want to click on divs link and open info on other div within same page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click on one divs link and open info on other div in same page. but i m not getting the expected result.

```js
$("#sidebar a").click(function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".toggle").hide();
  var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
  $(toShow).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <a href="#content1"</a><center>About NewLeaf</center><br>
      <a href="#content2"</a><center>Vission</center><br>
      <a href="#content3"</a><center>Cooperative Principles</center><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 
    </div>

  <div id="article">
    <div id="content1" class="toggle" style="display:none">showknfdkjgbjbjdf the stuff1</div> 
    <div id="content2" class="toggle" style="display:none">show the gffstuff2</div>
    <div id="content3" class="toggle" style="display:none">show thegd stuff3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Start by fixing your markup. Those hyperlinks are malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an element with the id `sidebar`. But there's only an element with class `sidebar`.

So change `$('#sidebar a')` to `$('.sidebar a')`

Answer (score 2):

Use `eq()` function to toggle corresponding div.

**Note**: Had to remove break-lines `br` from the DOM, to get right `indexes`. Use css styling instead.

```js
$(".sidebar a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.toggle').eq($(this).index()).toggle();
});
```

```css
a {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a href="#content1">
      <center>About NewLeaf</center>
    </a>
    <a href="#content2">
      <center>Vission</center>
    </a>
    <a href="#content3">
      <center>Cooperative Principles</center>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="article">
    <div id="content1" class="toggle" style="display:none">showknfdkjgbjbjdf the stuff1</div>
    <div id="content2" class="toggle" style="display:none">show the gffstuff2</div>
    <div id="content3" class="toggle" style="display:none">show thegd stuff3</div>
  </div>
</div>lt.
```

Comment: Looking forward for explanation from dv.

Comment: I would assume that's not what he wants. I think he wants only one `div.toggle` opened at a time. But who knows. I like the idea :P

Comment: @cyrix Yyy, he didn't wrote anything about closing other divs while one is visible, lets wait for his reply then (:

Comment: your code is running in stack overflow.but it dnt run on my machine.

Comment: lets do one thing, forget toggle and everything. jst write code for displaying info on other div.

Comment: @DipakPatel What do you mean? You want the other divs to hide, when the clicked one is visible?

Comment: i have two divs side by side..now in one div i have this three links.. when i click on one link, it should open corrosponding info in other div.

Comment: @DipakPatel But... this is exactly how it works now.

Comment: yes answers are proper..i think i need to chek my code..there might be some other div errors..thanks alot